# Implement custom std::string to encrypt and decrypt strings in real time

Tags: c++, stl, std, stdstring

I'm working on a project where all strings have to be encrypted(AES or any other encryption algorithm) in memory(memory dump protection) and also have to support various operations as such as `assign()`, `operator+=` etc.

During my implementation research, i have encountered several solutions; some mentioned to inherit from std::string(std::basic_string) but failed to provide a workaround for `std::string` lack of virtual destructor and also didn't really have any virtual functions to override for my purposes. Another solution, mentioned to override its template default arguments and provide custom `allocator` and `char traits`. While examining the given solution. though seemed promising at the time. i had several issues to properly override the following functions:

1. allocator::allocate
2. std::char_traits::copy

because `allocate` is called with the `strlen` value of the decrypted string, it felt like an additional function is needed to first calculate the size of the encrypted string and only then allocate it.

With the given c++11's implementation is something like this even plausible? i have so far failed finding any working solutions over the web.

My last options is to simply wrap std::string with my own custom class and provide adaption functions. `operator+=`, `assign`, `c_str()..`

Thanks!

Edit:

1. `std::string str = "Hello World"`, Would make std::string's member _Bx to have an encrypted string of "Hello World"
2. Any usage of c_str() or data() will be removed.

Comment: Encrypting from / decrypting to where?

Comment: I believe that inheriting from `std::basic_string` should not be a problem if you always use your derived type directly and never use it in a polymorphic manner. The lack of a virtual destructor is then no issue and you can override any method you want.

Comment: how would you implement c_str() or data() without breaking std::string guarantees *and* simultaneously guaranteeing no in-memory plaintext ?

Comment: I've modified the question, view Edit

Comment: ok, but that *would* break std::string guarantees, this seems not a good idea ... why do you want an std::string in the first place? can't you just write your own encrypted string class ? note that many things ( from char traits to allocator support ) makes little sense for such encrypted string facility ...

Comment: If I don’t find a suitable solution. I may write my own class

Comment: Think in terms of Encapsulation rather than inheritance